# How Inject configService in the index.route file in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im trying to read some Root Variables in the config file , i have a service for that and wen i try to inject in the routerConfig i have a error in the console

```html
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('App')
    .config(routerConfig);



  /** @ngInject */
  function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, configService ) {
```

error in console

> jquery.js:3850 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
>       Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: configService

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> - The [config](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#config) method accepts a function, which can be injected with "providers" and "constants" as dependencies. Note that you cannot inject "services" or "values" into configuration.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-dependency-injection)